# How make SSIS SQL Task between 2 servers

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I've 2 servers: Reporting and devsvr. I've SSIS on Reporting to take article's informations from providers. And On devsvr, I've a webSite to see my articles.
I make a linked between 2 servers. 
To connect on Reporting DataBase I use user : EDBV3. And To connect on devsvr user : MOS.
I connect on SQLServer Management on Reporting with EDBV3 account. Execute

```
INSERT INTO DEVSVR.extranet.dbo.EDBV3_Grossiste (IDGrossiste,Libelle ) SELECT IDGrossiste, Libelle FROM edb_v3.dbo.EDB_Grossiste where EDB_Grossiste.EstActif = 1
```

No problem.

When I put this on SSIS Package/ SQL Task. I create Reporting connexion with SQL Account EDBV3. Put my request in SQL Task. Execute this in SQL Agent on Reporting, I've error message : I'm not allowed to acces to extranet...

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I find the problem.
It's not on method.
I use config file for edbv3 access (cause I use it in lot of SSIS package)
But don't know why... For this package it's not ok on the server.
I include information in specific config file of this package, and it's good...